# Different activities within a tab and redirection between the tabs

Tags: android, tabactivity, activitygroup

In my application, I have multiple activities within a single tab. I am managing those by using Activity group. I wanted to ask, that if on one tab I am on the second or third activity, and then I move to the other tab and back to the same tab, how can I show the first activity. Now, it is showing the activity which I was on before moving to the next tab.

Please help me out in this.

Comment: wat do u mean by multiple activities within a single tab...

Comment: like under one tab, if I have list of items, when I click on any item, I go to the detail of that item but under/within the same tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
Intent i = new Intent(getParent(),your.class);
        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("class_title", i);
```